# Displaying an image after url is saved to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to save images and videos to a separate folder and not in the database, as from what I read it is best practice not to store there. I am able to take in the photo, then save the URL string to the database. Files are saving to the correct location.

After I pull up the view to display the image, it's not showing up. I can see it is a broken link. But not sure how to correct it.

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public  IActionResult AddPost(AddPostViewModel addPost, IFormFile file)
    {
        //Setting the extra data need for the post
        addPost.post.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        addPost.post.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;

        //Saving the image to a location 
        SaveImage saveImage = new SaveImage();
        Task<String> filePath = saveImage.UploadFile(file);

        addPost.post.PostImageVideo = filePath.Result;
        


        //Adding and saving the post to the database and then returning to the admin panel. 
        _context.Post.Add(addPost.post);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.SessionUserFirstName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserFirstName");
        ViewBag.isAdmin = HttpContext.Session.GetString("IsAdmin");
        return RedirectToAction("AdminPanel");
    }
```

The medthod being called to save the image:

```
public async Task<String> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        var fileName = "";
        var filePath = "";
        //adding the filepath to the database and saving the path. 
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
             fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
             filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),@"~/wwwroot/images/", fileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }

       
        return filePath.ToString();
        
    }
```

Then the view that pulls in the link from the entity or pulling from database

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Post";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1>@Model.post.Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!--This is grabbing the link for the post.-->
        <img src="@Model.post.PostImageVideo" />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>@Model.post.Body</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems like when I look at the link, it isn't grabbing the wwwroot folder that it is located in, it just goes right into the images. Not sure how to correct it.

Comment: What value you are storing in the database for uri of image? What value is being rendered in the HTML for the uri of the image?

Comment: I'm trying to store the picture in the wwwroot/images folder. seems the pictures are making it there. what is in the database now after tweaking the combine statement to: lePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"wwwroot/images/", fileName);
C:\Users\justi\source\repos\Blog\Blog\wwwroot/images/2years.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it:

When I called the saveImage method I was returning the filepath. I had it return the filename and put in and additional string in front to save to the database like so:

```
 addPost.post.PostImageVideo = "/images/" + fileName.Result;
```

Whether that is the correct way or not, not sure, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `FileContentResult` to return the image as file to view.

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;

    public ImageController(IHostingEnvironment appEnvironment)
    {
        _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public FileContentResult ShowImage()
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images\\avatar.png").Replace("\\", "/");

        byte[] imageData = null;
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);

        return File(imageData, "image/png");
    }
}
```

View..

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage", "Image", new { area = "" })" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```